# CORS policy returning No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Express Gateway

Tags: node.js, cors, cross-domain, api-gateway, express-gateway

I am using Express Gateway as my API gateway to connect with back end server. My front end runs on localhost:3000 and Express gateway runs on localhost:8080. When I try to access the back end from the front end , I get a cors error in my browser. However when using postman everything woks fine.

My gateway.config.yml (Only one pipeline)

```
user:
    apiEndpoints:
      - user
    policies:
      - cors:
        - action:
            origin: "*"
            credentials: true
            methods: ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE']
            allowedHeaders: ['Content-type','Authorization','Origin','Access-Control-Allow-Origin','Origin', 'Accept', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers','Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin','X-TEST']
            exposedHeaders : ['Content-type','Authorization','Origin','Access-Control-Allow-Origin','Origin', 'Accept', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers','Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin','X-TEST']
            preflightContinue: true
      - jwt:
        - action:
            secretOrPublicKey: 'secret'
            checkCredentialExistence: false
      - request-transformer:
        - action:
            body:
              add:
                user: req.user
      - proxy:
        - action:
            serviceEndpoint: noAuthService
```

I get the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/31a19f8a-c76d-4051-a944-dad1b676c550' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ???

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: yeah i had some issues in my gateway.yaml file .

Comment: thank you. I also faced some problem in the CORS and fixed.

Comment: Okay. I'm not using express gateway anymore. It's not actively developed. I'm using envoy proxy and it's been great so far. Great support from the community, highly scalable, high performance and much more pros. Have a look at that.

Comment: I'm using express gateway for small microservices redirection only so far applications are working fine. anyway, I'll check about envoy proxy sure. Thank you for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: @LahiruUdayanga can you help me with this ? I have the same error, please!!

Comment: @Jota The issue was i have't added OPTIONS in the methods list. So the preflight request cannot occur. See https://gist.github.com/NomadXD/05956bfe4158fee674d22fb7078cc5bb for a working example

Comment: @LahiruUdayanga thanks for replied... but it didn't work for me... I also put ["*"] to allow all methods, but the same problem

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that the presence of a custom header on the request triggered a pre-flight request to check for the right to CORS access, but your server did not respond appropriately to that pre-flight request so access was not granted.

It works fine with postman because postman does not enforce CORS.  The browser does enforce CORS.

My first question is why don't you just combine the gateway code into front-end server?  Why do you need two separate servers?

Then, to handle a pre-flight request, you need to handle an OPTIONS request (instead of GET or POST, the incoming http verb is OPTIONS) as illustrated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).  You can read about pre-flighted requests [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) and see some examples of how to handle them.  In Express, you would use

If you're using the `cors()` package, you can see some pre-flight handling examples [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight) and [here](https://flaviocopes.com/express-cors/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Why 2 servers ? Because I have structured my project as a micro services project and the API gateway is responsible for forwarding the requests to the relevant servers. I am using Express gateway as my API gateway. It provides out of the box feature to handle cors. https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/cors/  I did what it exactly says and couldn't get it working. Yeah from the frond end authorization and content-type headers are needed to send. The express gateway community is not much active now. Can you help me out please? Ready to provide more info.